# OfflineAudioContext only rendering and calling onComplete once

Tags: offline, web-audio-api, audiocontext

I've created an offline context to render a visualization based on the rendered buffer and call startRendering() to get the rendered buffer in the onComplete callback. If I try to create a new set of connected audio nodes, calling startRendering() again does nothing. Do I have to recreate the whole offline context for each render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's how it is supposed to work.

Comment: Ok. Seems a bit unintuitive when you only have to recreate a normal context's nodes to play it again, but you have you recreate the entire offline context to rerender.

Comment: Is it bad to reuse the normal audioContext as well? Or should I recreate it each time I play a set of nodes?